# Is there a better way to write a 2-dimensional array into a binary file?

Tags: c#, arrays, binary

I have a 2D array and would like to store in a binary file. To my knowledge, I wrote the following code to transfer the data into a binary file.

```
double[,] A = new double[nx,ny];
// put some data in the array
for (i = 0; i < nx ; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < ny ; j++)
    {
        A[i,j] = ...;
    }
}
string path = "address";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
for (i = 0; i < nx ; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < ny ; j++)
    {
        bw.Write(A[i,j]);
    }
}
bw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

This code works, but I need better way and faster method.
Any idea?

Comment: Whatever you do, start by benchmarking the performance so you can compare solutions. And then establish an expectation for what you'll consider "good enough" performance. How long does this take with the size of data that you have?

Comment: The BinaryFormatter will be the easiest. It Serializes pretty efficiently.

Comment: Writing to disk is what expensive here, x1000s more than anything in memory. Focus there (maybe buffering writes into bigger chunks etc.)

Comment: Writing 1 double at a time is not good.  Store in continuous byte[] array(s) and write that at one go if possible.  You can convert double to bytes using the BitConverter.GetBytes(double) method.

Comment: Do it as @Loathing said: Convert (in memory) to a byte array, then write this to file in one go. If the array is _really_ large, do the process steps for each row.

Comment: @Mehdi: Contrary what you're saying, your code could not have worked because it contained several syntax errors (`For` instead of `for`, missing `new` keyword). Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use binary serialization with the `BinaryFormatter` Class.

You will find lots of information in the net.
One example is: 
http://www.centerspace.net/examples/nmath/csharp/core/binary-serialization-example.php

Comment: BinaryFormatter is not well suited for persistent storage. If the assembly version changes for any of the types that are stored in your serialized file you will not be able to perform the deserialization. The intent of BinaryFormater is to be used for IPC communication on the same system, not for network transmission nor persistent storage.

Comment: BinaryFormatter is also slow. The question is asking for a FAST method.